# Hadoop filesystem reads linux filesystem instead of hdfs?

Tags: hadoop

I have a strange thing happening, when I read hadoop filesystem it shows me linux filesystem not the hadoop one, anyone is familiar with this issue?

Thanks,
Mika

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will happen if a valid hadoop configuration is not found.

e.g. if you do:

```
hadoop fs -ls
```

and there is no configuration is found at the default location, then you will see the linux filesystem. You can test this by adding either the `-conf` option after the "hadoop" command e.g.

```
hadoop -conf=<path-to-conf-files> fs -ls
```

Comment: aha, I see, I'm facing this when I do the map reduce app, so I guess need more config to do, will accept answer as soon as I confirm ;), thanks!